# vb.net How to read cell color in HTML table

Tags: html, excel, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I need to export an HTML table from a webbrowser to an Excel file.

```
    Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
    Dim table As HtmlElement = htmlDoc.GetElementById("Table1")
    Dim rows As HtmlElementCollection = table.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)

    
    For i As Integer = 0 To rows.Count - 1
        Dim cols As HtmlElementCollection = rows(i).GetElementsByTagName("td")
        For j As Integer = 0 To cols.Count - 1
            worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = cols(j).InnerText
        Next
    Next
```

The code above works fine.

I'd like now to copy the cells color so I have tried this code :

```
Dim color As String = cols(j).Style(backcolor)
Dim cell As Excel.Range = worksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1)
cell.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color)
```

And unfortunately it does not work.
The line `cols(j).Style(backcolor)` returns an exception error : cannot convert color value to integer value

Any idea ?

Comment: try 
> Dim color As String = cols(j).Style("backcolor")

Comment: I have already tried this, it returns the error : Impossible to convert string "backcolor" to integer

Comment: I had not realized that it was actually HTMLElement objects from WebBrowser. I post an answer wich can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only get full style string from htmlElement with htmlElement.style function. result looks like

```
BORDER-TOP: #aaaaaa 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #aaaaaa 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: #aaaaaa 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #aaaaaa 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #b0c4de
```

so you must extract style element from it by your own.
Example with split function as elements are separated by ';':

```
Dim StrStyle As String = cols(1).Style
            Dim color As String
            For Each param As String In StrStyle.Split(";")
                If param.Contains("BACKGROUND-COLOR") Then
                    color = param.Split(":")(1)
                    Dim c As Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color)
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: `StrStyle` is always Null or Empty. Maybe it does not detect the `<TR>` style ? I made it like this : `<tr bgcolor=#0C0C0C>`. Is this OK ?

Comment: I just try like this `<TR style = "background-color:#0C0C0C;">` but it remains Null or Empty.

Comment: Sorry, I did not set the style to the correct `<TR>` in my code. Your answer is the one !! But as I wrote, it needs the `<TR style = "background-color:#0C0C0C;">`. It does not work with `<tr bgcolor=#0C0C0C>`  THANK YOU !!!

Comment: for html attributes like bgcolor, you can use 
Dim StrStyle As String = cols(1).GetAttribute("bgColor")